# Cannot define properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am having an issue with my skillImage components.
I am not sure where the issue is coming from.
I get error message `cannot read properties of undefined : id` but it has been destructured correctly.
I have put below the following components involved, SkillContext, Skill, SkillsList.
The line of code in question is `const { skillCard: {id, skill} } = useContext(SkillContext);`

Can someone tell me what is wrong, please?
Thanks in advance

skill.js

```
import Image from "next/dist/client/image";
import { FaTimes, FaRegCalendarAlt, FaSchool,FaSpinner } from "react-icons/fa";
import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.scss'
//import  { FaStar } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { AiFillStar , AiOutlineStar } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { CourseFilterContext } from "../contexts/CourseFilterContext";
import { SkillProvider, SkillContext } from "../contexts/SkillContext";

function Course({ courseTitle, hours, level, year }) {
    return (
      <>
      <span className={styles.course}>
        <strong>Course :</strong> {courseTitle}{" "}
      </span>
      <span className={styles.course}>
        <strong>Hours: </strong> {hours}        
      </span>
      <span className={styles.course}>
        <strong>Level :</strong> {level}
      </span>
      <span className={styles.course}>
        <strong>Year :</strong> {year}
      </span>      
      </>
    );
  }
  
  function Courses() {
    const { courseYear } = useContext(CourseFilterContext);
    const { skillCard } = useContext(SkillContext);
    const courses = skillCard.courses;
    const level = skillCard.level;
    
    return (
      <div className={styles.courseBox, "h-250"}>
        {courses
        .filter(function (course) {
          return course.year === courseYear;
        })
        .map(function (course) {
          return (
            <Course {...course} level={level} key={skillCard.courses.id} />
          )
        })
        }        
      </div>  
    );
  }
  
  function SkillImage() {
     const { skillCard: {id, skill} } = useContext(SkillContext);
    ,
    return (
      <div className="speaker-img d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center h-300">
        <Image
          src={`/images/skill-${id}.png`}
          className="contain-fit"
          alt={`${skill}`}
          width="300"
          height="300"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  function SkillFavorite () {
    const { skillCard, updateRecord } = useContext(SkillContext);
    const [inTransition, setInTransition] = useState(false);

    function doneCallBack () {
      setInTransition(false);
      console.log(`In SkillFavorite: doneCallBack  ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`)
    }
    return (
      <div className={styles.icon}>
        <span onClick={function () {
          setInTransition(true);
          updateRecord(
            {
              ...skillCard, favorite: !skillCard.favorite,
            },
            doneCallBack
          )
          }}>
        { skillCard.favorite === false ?
        <AiFillStar fill="orange"/> : <AiOutlineStar fill="yellow"/>
        }{" "}
        Favorite{" "}
        { inTransition === true ? (
          <span><FaSpinner className="fa-spin" fill="orange"/></span>
        ): null}
        </span>
      </div>
    )

  }
  function SkillDescription() {
    const { skillCard } = useContext(SkillContext);
    const { skill, description, school, } = skillCard;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 className="text-truncate text-justify w-200">
          {skill}
        </h3>
        <SkillFavorite />
        <p className="text-justify skill-info">{description}</p>
        <div className="social d-flex flex-row mt-4 justify-content-between">
        <div className="school mb-2">
            {/* <FaSchool className="m-3 align-middle " fill="#000"/> */}
            <h5>School</h5>
            <h6>{school}</h6>
        </div>
        <div className="calendar mb-2">
            {/* <FaRegCalendarAlt className="m-3 align-middle " fill="#000"/> */}
            {/* <h5>Year</h5>
            <h6>{courses[0].year}</h6> */}
        </div>
        </div>        
      </div>    
    );
  }
  
  function SkillAction () {
    return (
      <div className="row mb-2">
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary w-100"
          onClick={() => handleEditClick()}
        >Edit
        </button>
        <div className="row mt-2">
          <FaTimes className="m-3 " fill="#ffc800" onClick={() => handleDeleteClick(idx)} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  function Skill({ skillCard, updateRecord, insertRecord, deleteRecord }) {
  
    const { showCourses } = useContext(CourseFilterContext);
    return (
      <SkillProvider skillCard={skillCard} updateRecord={updateRecord} insertRecord={insertRecord} deleteRecord={deleteRecord}>
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div className="card card-height p-4 mt-4 mb-2 h-300">
          <SkillImage />
          <div className="card-body">
            <SkillDescription />
            {showCourses === true ? 
            <Courses /> : null}
          </div>
          <div className="card-footer">
            <SkillAction />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </SkillProvider>
    );
  }

export default Skill;
```

SkillsList

```
import Skill from "../components/Skill";
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.scss";
import  ReactPlaceholder  from "react-placeholder";
import useRequestDelay, { REQUEST_STATUS} from "../hooks/useRequestDelay";
import { data } from '../../SkillData';
import { CourseFilterContext} from "../contexts/CourseFilterContext";
import { useContext } from "react";




function SkillsList () {

  const { 
    data: skillData, 
    requestStatus,
    error,
    updateRecord,
    insertRecord,
    deleteRecord
  } = useRequestDelay(2000, data)

  const { searchQuery, courseYear } = useContext(CourseFilterContext);
   
  if(requestStatus === REQUEST_STATUS.FAILURE) {
    return(
      <div className="text-danger">
        Error: <b>Loading Speaker Data Failed {error}</b>
      </div>
    )
  }
  //if (isLoading === true) return <div className="mb-3">Loading...</div>
    return (
        <div className={styles.container, "container"}>
          <ReactPlaceholder
          type="media"
          rows={15}
          className="skillsList-placeholder"
          ready={requestStatus === REQUEST_STATUS.SUCCESS}
          >
        <div className="row">
          {skillData
          .filter(function (skillCard) {
            return (
              skillCard.skill.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)               
          );
          })
          .filter(function (skillCard) {
            return skillCard.courses.find((course) => {
              return course.year === courseYear;
            })
          })         
        
          .map(function (skillCard) {         
            return (
              <Skill 
              key={skillCard.id} 
              skillCard={skillCard}              
              updateRecord={updateRecord}
              insertRecord={insertRecord}
              deleteRecord={deleteRecord}
              />
            );
          })}  
        </div>
        </ReactPlaceholder>
      </div>
    );
}

export default SkillsList;
```

SkillContext

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const SkillContext = createContext();

function SkillProvider({children, skillCard, updateRecord, insertRecord, deleteRecord}) {
    return (
        <SkillContext.Provider
        value={skillCard, updateRecord, insertRecord, deleteRecord}>
        {children}
        </SkillContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { SkillContext, SkillProvider}
```

Comment: Have you tried to conditionally display them like so in `skill.js file` `{id ? <SkillImage /> : 'No id found!'}`. Since at first load, the `id` will always be `undefined` untill it get replaced with whatever data you get from your API req.

Comment: @lala hi there, i have tried but i'm still running into the same error message.  thanks for trying

Comment: @peterkellner  Hi Peter, i have ran into this issue trying to adapt my project to the one in design better component course . Can you please help me spot where issue is?